# WP7 - Dynamically change the startup page depending on setting

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to change the startup page based on a setting in a windows phone 7 application?

For example, an app with 2 pages.  Lets say Movies, and News.  I'd like the user to be able to select which of the 2 pages they want to be shown first when launching the app.

Right now I'm trying to solve the problem by navigating to the correct page on startup but this causes funky back button behavior which is very bad.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can redirect page navigations without impacting the back stack. Peter outlines two approaches here.

[Redirecting an initial navigation - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)