# WP7 conditional start page

Tags: windows-phone-7

I know I can set up start page in WMAppManifest.xml file.

Is there a way to set start page based on some condition?

I have an application that have 'remember me' funcionality so when app starts I would like it to go directly to some page. If user is not remembered then show log in screen.

Now I show a page and in it's logic I check this and if necessary I navigate to other page.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,
Bartek

Answer (score 3):

From [this page](http://debugmode.net/2011/09/05/setting-start-page-of-windows-phone-dynamically-through-code/), in your `App.xaml.cs`:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    Uri nUri = new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Navigate(nUri);
}
```

Then open your `WMAppManifest.xml` file and clear the `NavigationPage` from the `DefaultTask` line.

```
<DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this "WP7 - Dynamically change the startup page depending on setting":-

[WP7 - Dynamically change the startup page depending on setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636283/wp7-dynamically-change-the-startup-page-depending-on-setting)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of any better ways of conditionally redirecting to different pages other than having a loading page which checks and does the redirect for you.